# How to link to CSS properly in WordPress header.php?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have been trying to create a WordPress theme but linking to style.css within header.php doesn't seems to work, the header just doesn't appear. Used more than 30 codes even the ones provided by WordPress and people with similar errors but it seems like the solutions are outdated.

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel = "stylesheet">
```

This is my PHP script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container"> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media<b class = "caret"></b></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Instagram</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Google Plus</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>   <a href="http://www.adds.com" class="navbar-btn btn-success btn pull-right">Add</a>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
```

Comment: where is your css file located ?

Answer (score 18):

Your theme `style.css` is included by default by the WordPress by `wp_head()` function. Before you end your HEAD tag add this function.

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

If you want to add additional stylesheets then use this function in your `functions.php` file.

```
function additional_custom_styles() {

    /*Enqueue The Styles*/
    wp_enqueue_style( 'uniquestylesheetid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'additional_custom_styles' );
```

Comment: Add `<?php wp_footer() ?>` to then it will display the wordpress bar

Comment: Style.css wasn't included by default for me. I had to add it manually.

Comment: Turns out I wasn’t inclusinf wp-head. Shoulda read harder before commenting.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/style.css' ?>">
```

And have that file (I usually place it in a header.php file) in the same directory as the style.css file?

This is what I do.

Comment: My source is a WordPress theme I work with on an almost daily basis, built from scratch. Are you sure your site is actually running PHP properly on that theme page? What do you see in source view by "link href="?

Comment: one shot answer thnak you

Answer (score 4):

For me this works great:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/style.css" />
```

Comment: where do you have your style.css? and how does the href="" look in the frontend?

Comment: <?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?> should give you the path to the template directory. Does that work?

Answer (score 3):

you can try this one

```
 <?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>
```

instead of this

```
<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>
```

from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri)

make sure your style.css file is in your theme's directory

Answer (score 1):

refer to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220719 
update the fuction.php file through the Wordpress Dashboard > Appearance > Theme Editor   theme files are listed on the right.

add the following to your function.php file

`wp_enqueue_style ('style-name', get_template_directory_uri().'/mystylefile.css');`

flush your word press cache and make sure you FTP the file up to the root of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Hope that helps

Comment: What version of wordpress? Where is your Stylesheet located?

Comment: What is the file named like?

Comment: That should just work fine. What is the result in the source of the HTML if your review your website?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following **under** wp_head();

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include css in header.php file as follow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url').'/custom.css'; ?>">
```

Answer (score -2):

Just include this in the header, don't put style.css here

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() ); ?>
```

if you are adding Bootstrap CDN then use that like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```